# How to get email of Derby-Login user

Tags: derbyjs

I can easily get the user id from model.get("session.userId"); I am having trouble finding out how to use this to get the user's email.

Comment: pretty sure you have to create the global

Comment: Not sure what that means...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Users collection, you can use the userId to get the user object which would have the user's email.

```
// in the controller
var userId = model.get('session.userId');
userEmail = model.get('users.' + userId + '.email');

// in the view
<div>#root.users[userId].email</div>
```

Hope that is helpful :)